# Get the Type of Error in ModelState

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to know the type of error in ModelState.

Example: Required, MinLenght, Invalid, etc

this is my filter code

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ActionArguments.Any(kv => kv.Value == null))
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid ModelState");
            }

            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item in actionContext.ModelState)
                {
                    var _key = item.Key;
                    var _value = item.Value;
                    var _errors = _value.Errors;
                    foreach (ModelError _erro in _errors)
                    {
                        //WHAT KIND OF ERRO? 
                    }

                }
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
```

and this is a simple object

```
 public class ObjetoNovo
        {
            [Required]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [MinLength(5)]
            [MaxLength(20)]
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            [EmailAddress]
            [Required]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public bool Ativo { get; set; }

        }
```

and this is a posible method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUsuario(ObjetoNovo obj)
    {            
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
    }
```

i need to list the erros by type in my filter, is possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: i'm creating a custom filter, and i need to manipulate then by types.

Comment: `if(_erro.GetType() == typeof(Required)) { //Do Something }` How about checking like this for example in your Foreach loop?

Comment: i'd debug but i found only Message and Exception (null by the way)